# extracting football score from user input

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm writing a program in python which will deal with user input for football scores. for example:
`Newcastle United 4 - 6 Manchester united`

above score can also be written as

`NUFC 4-6 MUFC` and also as `newcastle 4-6 manu` and so on......

my purpose is to extract the team names and the score:
`Newcastle United`,`4`,`6`,`Manchester United`.

I need suggestions on how this can be done. One way i could think of is Regular expression but i'm not well versed with regex, so i am seeking help here.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it looks like a score could be described as a list of 5 items:

1. arbitrary text
2. a string of digits
3. a hyphen
4. a string of digits
5. arbitrary text

and that there may or may not be a space on either side of the hyphen.

The following should work:

```
g = re.match("(.*) ([0-9]+) ?- ?([0-9]+) (.*)", user_input)
if g:
    team1 = g.group(1)
    team1_score = g.group(2)
    team2_score = g.group(3)
    team2 = g.group(4)
```

The numbers in the call to `group()` correspond to the parentheses in the regular expression, from left to right.

Comment: I wish i could tick all as answers but this one works for me, and its bit detailed. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The following regex would do it:

```
^(.*?) *(\d+) *- *(\d+) *(.*)$
```

Groups:

- Group 1: Left team
- Group 2: Left team score
- Group 3: right team score
- Group 4: right team

Comment: thanks, your solution seems to work only for `Newcastle United 4 - 6 Manchester united` and not for other examples mentioned, i have checked it here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Mgilson: but yours will accept tabs instead of spaces. @vineetrok works for me? Maybe you need to enable multiline regex, as this will check line by line, making sure it captures the whole line.

Comment: @Inductiveload: i tried your version on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ , i used my question as test text, but it doesnt seem to find anything.correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I tried it there too - like I said, you'll need to use it as a multi-line regex, or the anchors `^$` will match the start and end of the whole set of lines and will fail. This answer assumes a single line is either a score or not.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work ...

```
>>> re.match(r'(.*?)\s*(\d+)\s*\-\s*(\d+)\s*(.*)',s).groups()
('Newcastle United', '4', '6', 'Manchester united')
```